# Use current browser session in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I’m trying to automate the files I need to download from multiple sources. That being said, is there a safe way to use current browser authentication in python requests?

Ps: the sites are using okta sso for authentication with security key.

I’ve tried nothing yet.

Comment: You can always try copying cookies, localStorage/sessionStorage, and the user agent, but it's always possible (and probably) that they'll have some kind of protection from automation (e.g. a captcha)